# Using integrated python in c# to calculate F anova

Tags: python, c#, statistics

```
public AnovaTestResult AnovaWithTukeyHSD(Parameter parameter)
{
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic scipyStats = Py.Import("scipy.stats");

        // Extract the grouped parameter values from the Parameter object
        var groupedValues = parameter.GroupedParameterValues.Values.ToList();
        var groupNames = parameter.GroupedParameterValues.Keys.ToList();

        // Convert data groups to numpy arrays
        dynamic dataArray = new PyList();
        foreach (var kvp in parameter.GroupedParameterValues)
        {
            var groupName = kvp.Key;
            var values = kvp.Value;

            // Convert List<double> to PyObject
            PyObject pyValues = new PyList(values.Select(x => x.ToPython()).ToArray());
            dataArray.append(pyValues);
        }
        // Perform the ANOVA test
        dynamic result = scipyStats.f_oneway(dataArray);


        // Perform Tukey's HSD test for pairwise comparisons
        dynamic pairwiseResult = scipyStats.posthoc_tukey_hsd(dataArray);

        // Retrieve the test value
        double fStatistic = Math.Round(result[0].As<double>(), 3);
        string fTestString = fStatistic.ToString("0.000");

        // Retrieve the p-value
        double pValue = Math.Round(result[1].As<double>(), 3);
        string pValueString = pValue <= 0.001 ? "<0.001" : pValue.ToString("0.000");

        // Retrieve the pairwise comparison results
        List<string[]> pairwiseComparisons = new List<string[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pairwiseResult.shape[0]; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < pairwiseResult.shape[1]; j++)
            {
                double pairwisePValue = Math.Round(pairwiseResult[i, j].As<double>(), 3);
                string comparison = $"{groupNames[i]} vs {groupNames[j]}";
                string pairwisePValueString = pairwisePValue <= 0.001 ? "<0.001" : pairwisePValue.ToString("0.000");
                pairwiseComparisons.Add(new string[] { comparison, pairwisePValueString });
            }
        }

        // Create and return the result object
        return new AnovaTestResult
        {
            TestValue = fTestString,
            PValue = pValueString,
            PairwiseComparisons = pairwiseComparisons
        };
    }
}
```

```
dynamic result = scipyStats.f_oneway(dataArray);
Error : Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'at least two inputs are required; got 1.'
```

but data array in debug menu is :

```
"[0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 2.4, 2.5, 3.2, 3.5, 3.6, 3.8, 3.9, 4.2, 4.2, 4.5, 5.3, 5.8, 6.0, 6.0, 6.2, 6.4, 7.2, 7.4, 7.5, 8.8, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7]"
"[1.0, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 2.3, 2.5, 2.5, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1, 4.1, 4.4, 4.5, 4.5, 5.1, 5.6, 5.9, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.7, 7.9, 8.5, 8.9, 9.4, 9.8]"
"[0.6, 0.8, 1.1, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.4, 3.1, 3.4, 3.4, 3.5, 4.3, 4.7, 5.0, 5.2, 5.4, 5.6, 5.8, 6.1, 7.0, 7.1, 7.6, 8.0, 8.2, 8.9, 9.0, 9.4, 9.9]"
```

three arrays how do I make it receive arrays based on my data even if they're more than 3 , for more illustration the class of the Parameter which has the values I'm using

```
 public class Parameter
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool IsGroup { get; set; }
     public string NominalOrScale { get; set; }
     public string NormalOrAbnormal { get; set; }

     public List<double> ParameterValues { get; set; } = new List<double>();
     public Dictionary<double, List<double>> GroupedParameterValues { get; set; } = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>();
     public Dictionary<double, Dictionary<string, string>> FormattedValues { get; set; } = new Dictionary<double, Dictionary<string, string>>();
     public Parameter()
     {
         GroupedParameterValues = new Dictionary<double, List<double>>();
         ParameterValues = new List<double>(); // Initialize ParameterValues list in constructor as well
     }
 }
```

GroupedParameterValues  , key is the group number , 1 , 2 , 3 .... value is a list of values corresponding to these groups

I tried converting it to array but failed to do so , if you have any modification on this or even on the Function for calculating F anova